# Update sql cell value with their own cell value plus string character

Tags: mysql

i have table named Room

```
id| Name | Code
1 | Jhon | 1a1, 1a2
2 | Ran  | 1a1, 1a3, 1a4
3 | Yums | 1a1, 1a2, 1a4
```

I want to update Jhon's code to "1a1, 1a2, 1a3, 1a4" just adding "1a3" and "1a4" to the code value. Result :

```
id| Name | Code
1 | Jhon | 1a1, 1a2, 1a3, 1a4
2 | Ran  | 1a1, 1a3, 1a4
3 | Yums | 1a1, 1a2, 1a4
```

Can some one write the sql query please,

Comment: What do you have so far / what have you tried?

Comment: update room set code="(select code from room where name="Jhon");, 1a3, 1a4" where name="Jhon";

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete wrong design. Create a new table for your code column with the columns name id and code and Insert for each code a row. Then you can request the codes for a name with a join.